# Linear transport equation with Lipschitz conditions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, linear-pde

Given the equation [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/397816/linear-transport-equation-with-unbounded-coefficients), I would like to ask the following relaxed question:

Consider the PDE

$$\partial_t f(x,t) = \langle q(x), \nabla \rangle f(t,x) + p(x),$$

with Schwartz initial data $f(0,x) = f_0(x) \in \mathscr S(\mathbb R^n).$

I am wondering then if $q$ is Lipschitz and $p$ is Schwartz as $f_0$, does there exist a solution $(t,x)\mapsto f(t,x)$ for this equation that decays faster than any polynomial in the space variable $x$ for any fixed time $t>0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The anwer is **yes**.

**Preliminary observations:**

Let us first consider the case $p=0$.

Since $q$ is globally Lipschitz on $\mathbb{R}^n$, say with Lipschitz constant $L$, all solutions of the ODE $\dot x = q(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ exist globally and, if $(\varphi_t)_{t \in \mathbb{R}}$ denotes the induced flow in $\mathbb{R}^n$, each function $\varphi_t: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is Lipschitz continuous with constant $e^{|t|L}$ (this follows from Grönwall's lemma).

Since we assumed $p=0$, the solution of your PDE is given by
$$
  f(t,x) = f_0(\varphi_t(x)) \tag{*}\label{1}
$$
for each $t$ and $x$.

Hence, if $f_0$ decays faster than every polynomial, so does $f(t, \cdot)$ for each fixed time $t$.

Let us now phrase this in a more functional analytic language: For each integer $k \ge 0$, consinder the weight function $w_k: \mathbb{R}^n \to [1,\infty)$ given by $w_k(x) =1 + \lvert x \rvert^k$, and consider the Banach space $E_k$ of all continuous functions $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies $w_k f \in C_0(\mathbb{R}^n; \mathbb{R})$; we endow the space $E_k$ with the weighted supremum norm $\|\cdot\|_{w_k}$ given by
$$
  \|f\|_{w_k} = \|w_k f\|_\infty.
$$

It follows from $\eqref{1}$ that the *Koopman group* $(T_k(t))_{t \in \mathbb{R}}$ given by
$$
  T_k(t)f = f \circ \varphi_t
$$
for each $f \in E_k$ is a well-defined one-parameter group of bounded linear operators on $E_k$. Moreover, the orbits of the group are continuous with respect to the weak topology on $E_k$ (use that (i) $E_k$ is isomorphic to $C_0(\mathbb{R}^n; \mathbb{R})$ via multiplication with $w_k$, that (ii) for each $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, the mapping $t \mapsto \varphi_t(x)$ is continuous, and (iii) the Riesz representation theorem for measures on $C_0(\mathbb{R}^n; \mathbb{R})$).
Hence, by a standard result from $C_0$-semigroup theory, the the group $(T_k(t))_{t \in \mathbb{R}}$ is even continuous with respect to the strong operator topology, i.e., it is a $C_0$-group on $E_k$.

It is trivial, but important to observe, that the groups $(T_k(t))_{t \in \mathbb{R}}$ act consistently on the spaces $E_k$.

Using these preliminary observations, we can show:

**Theorem.** Let $p$ be continuous and decay faster than every polynomial.

(i) For each $f_0 \in C_0(\mathbb{R}^n; \mathbb{R})$ there exists a unique mild solution $f: \mathbb{R} \to C_0(\mathbb{R}^n; \mathbb{R})$ of the Cauchy problem
$$
  \dot f = \langle q, \nabla \rangle f(t) + p, \qquad f(0) = f_0.
$$

(ii) If $f_0$ decays faster than every polynomial and $f: \mathbb{R} \to C_0(\mathbb{R}^n; \mathbb{R})$ denotes the mild solution from (i), then for each fixed time $t \in \mathbb{R}$, the function $f(t)$ also decays faster (in space) than every polynomial.

*Proof.*
Fix $k \ge 0$. Since $(T_k(t))$ is a $C_0$-group on $E_k$ and since $p \in E_k$, it follows that, if $f_0 \in E_k$, the PDE has a unique mild solution $f: [0,\infty) \to E_k$ given by
$$
  f(t) = T_k(t)f_0 + \int_0^t T_k(s) p \, ds,
$$
where the integral is a Bochner integral in $E_k$. Applying this to $k=0$, we obtain (i).

Moreover, these solutions are consistent on the $E_k$-spaces (i.e., if $f_0 \in E_{k+1} \subseteq E_k$, then the mild solutions in $E_k$ and $E_{k+1}$ are the same). If $f_0$ decays faster than every polynomial, then we have $f_0 \in E_k$ for each $k$. Hence, for each time $t$ and each $k$, we have $f(t) \in E_k$. Thus, for each time $t$, the function $f(t)$ decays faster in space than any polynomial. $\square$

Comment: thank you, I guess it does not destroy the property, but how does one take the additional $p(x)$ into account?

Comment: cause I have the impression you are only solving the transport part without the $p(x).$

Comment: @PritamBemis: Ah, sorry - I completely forgot about $p$. I think this can be done by perturbation theory for $C_0$-semigroups in weighted spaces of continuous functions. I'm quite tired now, but I'll try to fix this tomorrow.

Comment: no problem, thank you for looking into this :)

Comment: @PritamBemis: Alright, I have now included the case $p \not= 0$. This makes the argument a bit more involved, though.

Comment: thank you, I am a bit confused about you saying $p$ bounded and continuous is enough. Let $q=0$ and $f_0=0$ then the solution is $f(t,x) = p(x)t$ and this will then not decay?

Comment: You seem to have misread the problem as $p(x)f$ rather than just $p(x)$. As it is stated, $p$ also has to decay faster than any polynomial.

Comment: Arrrgh! You're both right of course. It seems that I'm not on form... But of course, if $p$ decays faster than every polynomial, one can then simply use a convolution with the semigroup in each space $E_n$ to get the result. I'll edit in a few hours (have to go to a seminar now.) (@MichaelRenardy, and OP)

Comment: @PritamBemis: Alright, fixed. Sorry for the mess. (I probably shouldn't write MathOverflow posts when I'm in a hurry...)

Comment: @JochenGlueck no problem and thanks a lot :)

Comment: If you write down your formula explicitly $$f(t,x)=f_0(\phi(t,x))+\int_0^t p(\phi(t-s,x))\, ds$$ the argument for $p=0$ extends to $p \neq 0$. One needs that $|\phi(t,x)| \geq c|x|$ for $|x|$ large and the same $c$ for $t \in [0,T]$, which follow from the properties of $\phi$.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune: Good observation, thank you!